# Is it possible to log/trace JMS message ID for specific Queue?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, sap-erp, sap-pi

I'm by no means an MQ expert. However, I'm assigned a task to integration 3rd party Application --> MQ --> SAP PI --> SAP ECC

As we are facing problems on PI with duplicate (JMS) message IDs, I'd like to know if it is possible to log / trace which (JMS) messages with their respective IDs were put or retrieved from a queue.

My overall goal is to verify or falsify the assumption that the sending application or MQ is generating duplicate IDs.

3rd party app version = 7.1
queue manager version = 7.5

I hope this is not all too basic.

Comment: Which version of MQ are you using? Both the MQ queue manager and the MQ JMS client that the app is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It so happened that there was indeed a legacy MQ client program which occasionally didn't initialize all it's respective variables and hence created duplicate JMS IDs.

We found that out through extensive MQ tracing which happened on each hop the message flowed through.

Hope this helps somebody out there with a similar situation.
Cheers
Jens